# iMovie with Audio USB Interface

Tags: audio, usb, video, imovie

I am using iMovie for recording audio during a Lecture (I nees to see video during recording) with a M-Audio M-Track interface (two XLR microphone).

The thing is that I can only record first microhone, because I can-t select the interface BUS on iMovie (or I didn't see it).

I also tested record with a XENYX UFX1204 (12 inputs), but I can only record from first input to.

Can anybody please help me?

Grateful

MacBook, iOS 9.2.1

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Create an Aggregate Device in MIDI Settings.
2. Use [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) app (free) and [LineIn](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) to route/combine inputs.

For total control, [Rogue Amoeba Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) (paid app) can create (and save) virtually any routings/combinations you want as inputs to any Mac app.